# Huge time difference between production and developer in running the same query on Oracle database from a Spring Boot Rest service

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I have the same query that on the production server completes in 6 seconds and on the developer server completes in 1.40 minutes!

It's a Spring Boot webservice accessing the database through a JDBC driver with connection pooling (ojdbc8', version: '19.3.0.0' and 'ucp', version: '19.6.0.0').

The same code,with the same settings/configuration produces the horrific results above just by changing the URL of the data source connection from production to developer machine. Everything runs on the local network.

On both servers there's Oracle Enterprise 12c and when connecting with SQL Developer the raw query runs fast, so it's not an issue with SQL.

What could be the bottleneck?

Comment: There's not enough information to even make a speculation. You should investigate your performance problem instead of making us guess what it is.

Comment: That's the point of asking.can you tell me where to start looking instead of being negative?

Comment: Does the query return a large amount of data? If so, could it be a network problem? When you ran the queries in SQL Developer, did you count the time to retrieve all the rows, or just the time to retrieve the first N rows? (Some SQL problems don't show up in the first N rows.)

Comment: Any obfuscation layers involved? Hibernate, JPA?

Comment: @microwth, I'm not so much being negative as I'm hinting at there being an enormous amount of data that's missing from this question, essentially making it either an outright unaswerable one, or an opinion-driven one (because it's always an opinion of where should you look). Neither of which strictly on-topic here. As for the amount of data, I could go as low as DB stat optimizer, but what good will it make if I can't exclude easier to tackle layers first? And as I already said, only you can narrow the search down.